# Regarding function syntax of topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity

In in the Separation Axioms section of *Schaum's General Topology*, the notion of point separation is mentioned briefly which is then followed by a short proposition. Attached below is the definition and proposition.

[image]

I have a concern with this proof. The author uses the notion that $\mathbb{R}$ is a Hausdorff space to show that that the space $X$ is Hausdorff. But I don't believe this is true. $\mathbb{R}$ is merely a set, not a space. It might be argued that $\mathbb{R}$ needs to be endowed with *some* topology, but no topology was mentioned. Now, had the author said that $\mathbb{R}$ was endowed with the natural open ball topology, then it certainly would be a Hausdorff space.

I suppose my question comes down to an issue of function notation / syntax. In lower level maths, we are brought up with the notion that when we see $f:X \to Y$, we see a function that inputs and outputs values from *sets*: namely, a domain and a codomain. But these are merely sets with no topology endowed upon them.

So, to make a long story short, in the proof for Proposition $10.9$, does the author need to make a mention of what topology $\mathbb{R}$ is endowed with? Because, like I said, when I see $f:X \to Y$, I see a relationship between two sets at bare minimum, but not necessarily two topological spaces.

Comment: $C(X,\mathbb R)$ doesn’t mean anything unless $X$ and $\mathbb R$ are topological spaces. $C$ is short for “continuous” here, and you can’t define continuous functions without topologies.

Comment: It almost seems like what you're saying is that functions are only continuous with respect to the topologies endowed on the spaces they utilize

Comment: When $\mathbb R$ is referenced as a topological space, it is assumed, without words to the contrary, that it refers to $\mathbb R$ with the standard real topology. Hint

Comment: Yes, functions are not continuous on sets. Different topologies give different continuous functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author talks about the "class $C(X,\Bbb R)$ of real-valued continuous functions": this has some implicit assumptions: we mean the functions from $X$ (a given **space** with a pregiven topology) to $\Bbb R$ (which *always* has, unless another topology is explicitly mentioned, the natural topology induced from its metric (or equivalently order), that are *continuous* (w.r.t. those two topologies; we always need $2$ topologies to talk about continuity).

So the proof is perfectly fine one you talke that in account. Always look at context: maths is not a purely formal game where everything is completely spelled out in notation and if things are well-known or standard in a certain context they're no longer mentioned (or expressed in notation).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, when we are being extra careful, we write $f:(X,\tau):\to (Y,\rho),$ where $\tau,\rho$ are topologies on $X,Y,$ respectively.

But usually, we just write $f:X\to Y.$ when there is an implied topology. In particular, if we are given that $X$ is a topological space, there is an implied single topology on $X.$

Unless the conditions are quite specific to say it is not true, when discussing continuity involving $\mathbb R^n,$ we assume the usual topology, derived from the Euclidean metric.

Essentially “$X$ is a topological space” can be treated as

> $X$ is an alias for a pair $(X_0,\tau),$   where $X_0$ is a set and $\tau$ is a topology on $X_0.$

The only time this risks confusion is when we talk about multiple topologies on the same set. $(X,\tau_1)$ and $(X,\tau_2)$ are different spaces, with the same underlying set.

It’s a pretty common shorthand. In group theory, a homomorphism is a function having certain properties, and they can be written: $$f:(G,1_G,\cdot_G)\to (H,1_H,\cdot_H)$$ but we usually just shorthand it to $f:G\to H,$ with the implied structures of the groups.